# Applescript keystroke Filepath variable

Tags: applescript, automator

I am trying to create a script that will upload products for me using Applescript and Automator. Im getting an error when the script tries to use the variable for the file path as it iterates through my list. The code is below. I am also inputing the contents of a folder from automator into this script. The error is on line 22. Also, if you could help with the second keystroke on line 42 which needs to iterate with the repeat but in a different folder. Thanks in advance!

```
on run {input, parameters}

repeat with theItem in input
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('btn-com btn-info btn-large btn-icon-left add-product-button')[0].click();" in document 1
        delay 1
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('btn-com btn-info btn-large btn-icon-left add-product-button')[0].click();" in document 1
        delay 1
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('editor_commerce_product_short_description').innerHTML = 'All photos include full rights to the image and arrive via email. Comes in full 4K resolution. Image displayed is 1080P resolution. Orders may take up to 2 hours to be delivered. Watermarks will be removed!';" in document 1
        delay 1
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('editor_commerce_product_price').value = '1.99';" in document 1
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('btn dropdown-toggle selectbox-display')[0].click();" in document 1
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('selectbox-content')[1].click();" in document 1
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('w-upload-input')[2].click();" in document 1
    end tell

    delay 1

    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "G" using {command down, shift down}
        delay 1
        keystroke theItem
        delay 1
        keystroke return

        delay 1
        keystroke return

        delay 1

    end tell

    delay 60

    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('w-upload-input')[1].click();" in document 1
    end tell

    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "G" using {command down, shift down}
        delay 1
        keystroke "~/Desktop/Test_Samples/Test_1.png"
        delay 1
        keystroke return

        delay 1
        keystroke return

        delay 1

    end tell

    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('save-product btn-com btn-success')[0].click();" in document 1
    end tell
end repeat

return input
```

end run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the class of `input / theItem`. Keystrokes must be `text`, `input` can be anything.

Try

```
keystroke (theItem as text)
```

or

```
keystroke (POSIX path of theItem)
```

And in `System Events` the equivalent of <kbd>⇧⌘G</kbd> is

```
keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked by combining both of the statements. keystroke (POSIX path of theItem as text)